# Where is the match validation for reset password in OpenERP [V8 Odoo]

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, openerp-8, odoo-8

I was trying to add more security politics, but I can't find where is the match validation for the 2 fields **Password** and **Confirm Password**, I was putting intensionally 2 different passwords in the fields to see the red advertisement, and I look in **auth_singup** module (/view/auth_signup_login.xml) and I only found the template to the view below.
[image]

- Can you help me find where OpenERP is validating this fields.
- Optional: Where is the best place for add new security politics(size>6, alphanumeric, especial character, etc).
  Thanks for you time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just searched for "passwords do not match" and IntelliJ took me to

`addons/auth_signup/controllers/main.py:116.`

This is where an `assert` is introduced to check if the passwords match. The simplest thing would be to add an `assert` with your custom message, following their example. Good luck!